# How to fetch a value from an Array

Tags: javascript, lightning

I am trying to get **margins** from below array based on **ProgramName**:

```
Programs:
Array(5)
0:{ProgramCode: "Bank1", ProgramName: "Service 1", InitialIndexName: "a", margins: Array(4)}
1:{ProgramCode: "Bank2", ProgramName: "Service 2", InitialIndexName: "b", margins: Array(8)}
2:{ProgramCode: "Bank3", ProgramName: "Service 3", InitialIndexName: "c", margins: Array(11)}
3:{ProgramCode: "Bank4", ProgramName: "Service 4", InitialIndexName: "d", margins: Array{4}}
4:{ProgramCode: "Bank5", ProgramName: "Service 5", InitialIndexName: "e", margins: Array(3)}
```

Here is my logic to fetch margin but I am getting it as undefined

```
var Parseddata =[];
var data = data.getReturnValue();
var json = JSON.parse(wsData);
json.Programs.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.ProgramName == 'Service 5'){                                              
            Parseddata = JSON.parse(data.getReturnValue()).margins;                 
    }
});
```

how can I get modify this

> Parseddata = JSON.parse(data.getReturnValue()).margins;

to get margins of Service 5 ProgramName.

I don't want to use programs[4] as below

> Parseddata = JSON.parse(data.getReturnValue()).Programs[4].margins;

because array  keeps changing.

please let me know if I am not clear, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to parse once: after the parsing you have JavaScript objects.

With some assumptions about the data structure, if the aim is to extract the margins of the 'Service 5' item then:

```
var margins = [];
var data = data.getReturnValue();
var json = JSON.parse(data);
json.Programs.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.ProgramName == 'Service 5') {                                          
        margins = item.margins;
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank u so much, this worked!